# Chromedriver.exe is viewed as a file from IntelliJ

Tags: java, selenium

Intellij sees my chromedriver exe as a file not as an executable and every time I run the program the error appears **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist**
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error comes when your chrome driver is not able to access your chrome.exe. Reinstall your chrome in C:/Programfiles(x86)/Google/ or in some commonly accessible place by all user. You may specify your chrome.exe location in case you don't want to Re install again.

```
File ChromeExePath =new File("Your Chrome.exe installation path");
if (ChromeExePath.exists()){
    options.setBinary(ChromeExePath);
}
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the property like this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path-to-chrome-driver");
```